# What component marketplaces are available online?

Tags: java, components, ejb

I am looking to install a COTS for a business im looking to start up. I was wondering if anyone had any experience with any available marketplace website. I have only managed to stumble across www.componentsource.com but I was wondering if there was another source I could access for components to install on my Java EE platform.

Many thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sites such as FreshMeat (http://freshmeat.net/) have some components and http://java-source.net/ has allot of open source Java.